# How can I use first() and last() to solve this problem?

Tags: kotlin

Imagine you have a 2D list inputList,whose dimension is greater than or equal to two. Print all of its corner elements in the following the clockwise order: left to right and top to bottom.

Print the result for two elements in one line. Use a single space to separate two elements on the same line.

```
fun main() {
    // Do not touch code below
    val inputList: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = mutableListOf()
    val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
    for (i in 0 until n) {
        val strings = readLine()!!.split(' ').toMutableList()
        inputList.add(strings)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should be improved to get the best help. 
What have you tried?
Which part isn't working for you?
Is there a specific part of the code that you don't understand?
I'm sure the answer to this question probably already exists on SO, so I would encourage you to continue reasearching.
Here is a guide on asking good questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

P.S. This reads like a homework question, and the comment in the code also makes it seem like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some questions you can answer (for yourself) that will help you understand what you're doing, and make it easier to answer your own question.

- When you input your data, what does the resulting data structure look like? You're using `List`s - what lists do you end up with, and how are they organised? Maybe use a 3x3 set of input value (you could do 1-9, like sudoku) and work out what you end up with and where those values go
- Once you've done that, how would you access the first or second value of each line? How do you access the middle number in that 9x9 grid? If you have a given `row` and `column`, what do you need to do with the list structure to get to the cell you need?
- If you've got the hang of that, the rest is easy. Where are the corners in terms of rows and columns? And if `first()` and `last()` give you the first and last items in a list, how does that relate to the rows and columns? Can you use those functions to get the corners?

Comment: This is what I tried but it didn't work
    // write your code here
    val numRows = inputList.size
    val numCols = inputList0.size
    val topLeft = inputList00
    val topRight = inputList0numCols - 1
    val bottomLeft = inputListnumRows - 10
    val bottomRight = inputListnumRows - 1numCols - 1
    println("$topLeft $topRight")
    println("$bottomLeft $bottomRight")
}

Comment: @ArtemRiabchikov what you wrote isn't valid Kotlin - I think I know what you're trying to do, and it's along the right lines, but your code there won't compile. Have a read of this (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-elements.html) and update your question with the code you've tried (in a code block, like your question code) so people can help you with it